# laravel 5 redirect in route model binding not working

Tags: laravel-5

I'm trying to use Route Model Binding with redirect instead of throwing not found exception. My RouteServiceProvider's boot function:

```
    $router->model('user', 'App\User', function(){
        return redirect()->route('show-users.get');
    });
```

But got nothing. Redirect not working. Code in routes.php

```
Route::post('user/edit-user/{user?}', [
    'as' => 'edit-user.post',
    'uses' => 'UserController@postEditUser',
    'permission' => 'edit_user',
    'middleware' => ['auth','check']
]);
```

Answer (score 11):

Add `send()` at the end:

```
return redirect()->route('show-users.get')->send();
```

Comment: that's awesome to know! the `return` caused an error in the logs though, works without it as well.